# Why does the magnitudes of output during inference correlate with the batch size during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have to say this might be one of the weirdest problems I've ever met.
I was implementing ResNet to perform 10-classification over cifr-10 with tensorflow. Everything seemed to be fine with the training phase -- loss decreased steadily, and accuracy on training set kept increasing to over 90%, however, the results were totally abnormal during inference.
I have analyzed my code very carefully and ruled out the possibility of making mistakes when feeding the data or saving/loading the model. So the only difference between the training phase and the test phase lies in batch normalization layers.

For BN layers, I used `tf.layers.batch_normalization` directly and I thought I've paid attention to every pitfall in using `tf.layers.batch_normalization`.

Specifically, I've included the dependency for `train_op` as follows,

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
            with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
                self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.losses)
```

Also, for saving and loading the model, I've specified `var_list` as `tf.global_variables()`. Moreover, I used `training=True` for training and `training=False` for test.

Nevertheless, the accuracy during inference was only around 10%, even when applied to the same data used for training. And when I output the last layer of the network (i.e., the 10-dimension vector input to softmax), I found that the magnitude of each item in the 10-dimension vector during training was always 1e0 or 1e-1, while for inference, it could be 1e4 or even 1e5. **The strangest part was that I found the magnitude of the 10-dimension vector during inference correlated with the batch size used in training, i.e., the bigger the batch size, the smaller the magnitude.**

Besides, I also found that the magnitudes of `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` of BN layers correlated with the batch size too, but why was this even possible? I thought `moving_mean` means the mean of the entire training population, and so was `moving_variance`. So why was there anything to do with the batch size?

I think there must be something that I don't know about using BN with tensorflow. This problem is really gonna drive me crazy! I've never expected to deal with such a problem in tensorflow, considering how convenient it is to use BN with PyTorch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved!
I read the source code of tensorflow. Based on my understanding, the value of `momentum` in `tf.layers.batch_normalization` should be 1 - 1/num_of_batches. The default value is 0.99, which means the default value is most suitable when there are 100 batches in training data.

I didn't find any documents mentioned this. Hope this can be helpful to someone who would have the same problem with BN in tensorflow!